# Problems updating state in simple React Notes APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing a notes APP in react that every note contains title and text and another functions that is not relevant for the question
The problem I am facing is that every time I change the title input its changes the title of all my previous results . My text input its working as expected . Can anyone give me a help in what I doing wrong or what can I do for solving it ?

```
function NotesList({ noteText, noteIndex, deleteHandler, noteTitle }) {

<span className='elementmodal'><h4 className='titlemodal'>{noteTitle}</h4>
                  {noteText}<button onClick={toggleModal} className='closebutton'>x</button></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        )}<span style={{ fontSize: '14px', margin: '4px' }}>{noteText}</span><button onClick={() => deleteHandler(noteText, noteIndex)} className='closebutton'>x</button>
```

```
function AddNotesComponent() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [note, setNote] = useState({title:'',text:''});
  



  const addNote = () => {
   
    const newItem = note.text + '(' + settingDate() + ')';
    
    
    
    note.text && setResult([...result, newItem  ])
    

  }
```

```
  const HandleTitle = (e) => setNote({...note,title: e.target.value});


  const HandleText = (e) => setNote({...note,text: e.target.value});
```

```
return (
    <>
      <div className='notebox'>
        <input style={{ width: '425px', marginTop: '5px' }} onChange={HandleTitle} placeholder='title'></input>
        <textarea style={{ width: '425px', marginTop: '15px' }} onChange={HandleText} placeholder='your note...'></textarea>
        <button className='addbutton' onClick={addNote}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <div className='resultdiv'>
        {result.map((item, index) => (<NotesList
          key={index}
          noteIndex={index}
          noteTitle={note.title}
          noteText={item}
          deleteHandler={closeNoteHandle}
        />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REASON**

Because in you current implementation you are passing note.title to a NotesList component which will surely be change for each time you need to replace it with the item. You got from result array. Also you are not saving title in result array you need to do that also

**STEPS FOR SOLUTION**

**CHANGE THIS**

```
const newItem = note.text + '(' + settingDate() + ')';
```

**TO THIS**

```
const newItem = {text: note.text + '(' + settingDate() + ')',title:note.title};
```

and then you need to change here as well

**THIS**

```
{result.map((item, index) => (<NotesList
          key={index}
          noteIndex={index}
          noteTitle={note.title}
          noteText={item}
          deleteHandler={closeNoteHandle}
        />
))}
```

**TO THIS**

```
{result.map((item, index) => (<NotesList
          key={index}
          noteIndex={index}
          noteTitle={item.title}
          noteText={item.text}
          deleteHandler={closeNoteHandle}
        />
))}
```

Comment: I understood the logic its working thank you =)

Comment: Good to know that it works. kindly approve it as correct answer @MateusRosengartenMauricio

Answer (score 0):

From a first glance, your map seems to take `note` as the current item through all its iterations, try the following change

```
 <div className='resultdiv'>
    {result.map((item, index) => (<NotesList
      ...
      noteTitle={item.title} // only change
      ...
    />
    ))}
 </div>
```